# Save ID instead of Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have which stored Country Name. But instead of that, I want to store Country ID.

Here is my code:-

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mkey))
        {  
          insertUpdateQuery = "UPDATE B_Order_new SET ShipName = :ShipName, ShipCity = :ShipCity, ShipAddress = :ShipAddress, " +
                                 "ShipCountry = :ShipCountry, OrderDate = :OrderDate, Sent = :Sent where MKEY = :MKEY";
        }
        else
        {
            insertUpdateQuery = "INSERT INTO B_Order_new (MKEY, ShipName, ShipCity, ShipAddress, ShipCountry, OrderDate, Sent) " +
                                 "VALUES(:MKEY, :ShipName, :ShipCity, :ShipAddress, :ShipCountry, :OrderDate, :Sent)";
        }

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insertUpdateQuery, myConn);

        var orderedOn = DateTime.ParseExact(orderDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("MKEY", OracleType.Number).Value = decimal.Parse(mkey).ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ShipName", OracleType.VarChar).Value = shipName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ShipCity", OracleType.VarChar).Value = shipCity;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ShipAddress", OracleType.VarChar).Value = shipAddress;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ShipCountry", OracleType.VarChar).Value = shipCountry;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("OrderDate", OracleType.DateTime).Value = orderedOn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Sent", OracleType.Char).Value = true;
}
```

Also see my select query that how I am binding it.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdCombo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleConn %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleConn.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME from country_test">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

my gridview where I am binding that dropdownlist

```
<obout:ComboBox runat="server" ID="ComboBoxEditor" FolderStyle="ComboBox/styles/premiere_blue"
            Width="100%" Height="150" MenuWidth="175" DataSourceID="sdCombo" DataTextField="COUNTRY_NAME"
            DataValueField="COUNTRY_NAME" OpenOnFocus="false">
            <ClientSideEvents OnBlur="persistFieldValue" OnOpen="ComboBox_Open" />
        </obout:ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your ComboBox's `DataValueField="COUNTRY_NAME"` to `DataValueField="COUNTRY_ID"`, this will load the country_Id to the ComboBox, then you can assign the ComboBox's `SelectedValue` to `shipCountry` variable, for storing the Country Id.

**Edit**: You can assign it as:

```
shipCountry=ComboBoxEditor.SelectedValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("ShipCountry", OracleType.VarChar).Value = shipCountry;
```

Change your ComboBox's Script to bellow:

```
<obout:ComboBox runat="server" ID="ComboBoxEditor" FolderStyle="ComboBox/styles/premiere_blue" Width="100%" Height="150" MenuWidth="175" DataSourceID="sdCombo" 
DataTextField="COUNTRY_NAME" DataValueField="COUNTRY_ID" OpenOnFocus="false"> 
<ClientSideEvents OnBlur="persistFieldValue" OnOpen="ComboBox_Open" /> </obout:ComboBox>
```

Comment: i already did that, can you tell me further steps in detail. I mean by writing the code

Comment: I tried your way, but I am getting `CountryID` on the front end but I want `CountryName` on front end and it's ID to  be saved into the database

Comment: I think you placed the COUNTRY_ID both in the text & value field of comboBox, I edited my answer from which you can take the right script of ComboBox which is desired to be formatted as.

Comment: NO, i placed it correctly. have a look here `<obout:ComboBox runat="server" ID="ComboBoxEditor" FolderStyle="ComboBox/styles/premiere_blue"
                Width="100%" Height="150" MenuWidth="175" DataSourceID="sdCombo" DataTextField="COUNTRY_NAME"
                DataValueField="COUNTRY_ID" OpenOnFocus="false">
                <ClientSideEvents OnBlur="persistFieldValue" OnOpen="ComboBox_Open" />
            </obout:ComboBox>`

Comment: As per OBOUT documentation here : https://www.obout.com/combobox/aspnet_selection_single_get.aspx , all you did is on the right way, but now if it is not working then needed to look at the full script & code-behind, or you can try once the ASP.NET standard dropdownList.